# How to turn a binary file into a variable in the c language?

Tags: c

That's what I tried I couldn't figure out why it didn't work

```
char* fileToVariable(char* filename)
{
   
    FILE* file = NULL;
    int i = 0, size = 0;
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(file);
    printf("%d\n", size);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));
    char ch = ' ';
    while ((ch = (char)fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        string[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    string[i] = '\0';
    return string;
}
```

Comment: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`. Can you provide a [mre] that we can compile and run? What does (or does not) work about your code?

Comment: (#268 C11dr §7.21.3 9)

*"Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any stream with state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in the initial shift state."*

Comment: Why do you deliberately cast the return of `fgetc()` to a `char` knowing that it returns an `int` and then go on to compare it with `EOF`?

Comment: `ftell()` returns a `long`, not an `int`.

Comment: You have no error handling – what if `fseek` fails? Check its return value! Test, too, if `ftell` returned < 0, then it failed, too. In any such case you cannot reliably read the file contents.

Comment: `while ((ch = (char)fgetc(file)) != EOF)` a `char` might not be able to hold `EOF`. Therefore the return type is `int`. The difference matters.

Comment: Your code risks invoking undefined behaviour by ignoring the return of `malloc()`. Subsequent operations on the returned pointer would invoke undefined behaviour if it was `NULL`.

Comment: Aside: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()`. It's redundant. Reading the file one character at a time is inefficient, consider using `fread()`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's called loading(or reading) file into memory.
Also you can't rely on null-terminating, since null can be anywhere inside of file.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct FileInMemory {
    void *ptr;
    size_t size;
};

//if returned FileInMemory.ptr == NULL, an error has occurred
struct FileInMemory fileToVariable(char* filename)
{
    FILE *file = NULL;
    struct FileInMemory data = {NULL, 0};
    long size = 0, ret;
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Failed to open file");
        return data;
    }
    ret = fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(file);
    if (size == -1 || ret == -1) {
        //For example on 32-bit systems with 32-bit offsets(EOVERFLOW)
        perror("Failed to get file size");
        goto ret;
    }
    printf("%ld\n", size);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    data.ptr = malloc(size);
    if (data.ptr == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to allocate memory");
        goto ret;
    }
    data.size = (size_t)size;
    fread(data.ptr, 1, size, file);

    //Closing file and returning
    ret:
    fclose(file);
    return data;
}
```